# How important is water condensation in maintaining the swirling winds of tornadoes?

Tags: water, wind, tropical-cyclone, storms, tornado

If we somehow removed all the water from Earth, it seems that there would no longer
be tornado-like 100+ mph winds (or, at least, this would be a much rarer occurrence).
Discussing storm creation, however, gets complicated, so let me instead ask here about
storm maintenance.

What would happen to a tornado-forming supercell or hurricane if we could somehow
switch off water's phase transformation?  In other words, in an accurate simulation
of these storms, if we suddenly (in the middle of a strong storm) disabled water
condensation into droplets (and disabled the reverse evaporation process, which
might be important for hurricanes), would wind speeds be significantly lower after,
say, 10 minutes?  How much lower?

I'm trying to understand how much the thermal heat of vaporization and the
rapid falling of droplets physically "stir" the storm (e.g., from [convective instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convective_instability)).  The simplest picture of
tornado development just requires a low-pressure center, but most sources say that
the dew point is usually above 55F, so water plays some role.  Is there any
published simulation to help quantify this role?  For a hurricane, it especially
seems that some physical property of water is crucial (beyond just providing a
good source of heat from the ocean's high thermal mass, as the textbook explanation
of a hurricane describes it).